# Is a verb missing from "...the company had turned away from DJs and towards the audiophile market..."?

Tags: ellipsis, reported-speech, backshifting

From the article [Technics’ new “standard” SL-1200GR turntable expected to cost $2,000](http://www.factmag.com/2017/01/06/technics-sl-1200gr-turntable-price/) on factmag.com:

> Earlier this week, Technics’ creative director Hiro Morishita told The New York Times why the company had turned away from DJs and towards the audiophile market with its reissued line of turntables.

I think a verb is missing in this sentence

> Earlier this week, Technics’ creative director Hiro Morishita told The New York Times why the company **had turned** away from DJs and  **turned**  towards the audiophile market with its reissued line of turntables.

The fact of turning towards at the time of speaking (earlier this week) is still true so that should not be past perfect but past simple even it is reported speech

Comment: What verb do you think is missing? What is the ordering of events using past perfect vs simple perfect?

Comment: verb missing turned (towards) order of events had turned away then turned towards and last the telling ,but you cant put had turned away and turned towards at the same moment one is before

Comment: @G-Cam What makes you think that the "towards" variant is an adverb?

Comment: @user5577 It's effectively a report of Technics’ creative director Hiro Morishita had said to The New York Times. Such reports, notably reported speech, are typically backshifted. The original utterance by Hiro Morishita would have been the present perfect "The company has turned away from DJs and towards the audiophile market with its reissued line of turntables because ..."

Comment: It may be worth noting that this proposed change effectively changes nothing.  It hardly matters whether the participle "turned" occurs inside or outside the coordination.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence is proper. *Turn*, like many verbs of motion, ordinarily takes a preposition phrase as its complement; in this case it takes a conjunction of two preposition phrases:

```
                              away from DJs 
 ... the company had turned  and 
                              toward the audiophile market ...
```

It's a single 'turn'—when you turn away from one direction you must pretty much by definition turn toward another at the same time.

Comment: But at the time of speaking the company was still into rthe audiophile market so why backshifting?

Comment: @user5577 You haven't given us a link; but I imagine that the author was speaking of the (prior) moment in time when the company decided to direct its future efforts toward a different market.

Comment: Technics' new "standard" SL-1200GR turntable expected to cost $2,000
www.factmag.com This is the link